# AJAX data not posting using FullCalendar when trying to update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have a calendar.php file which looks up "php/get-events" to display calendar events from the database (This currently works as expected). I am trying to use "php/calendarupdate" to then update the database with the new start/end times that have been dragged, but the data posting to this page always comes back as undefined, so it's not finding it for some reason.

```
"Calendar.php"

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      initialDate: '2021-03-18',
      editable: true,
      
    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   start=moment(event.start).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   end=moment(event.end).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   $.ajax({
   url: 'php/calendarupdate.php',
   data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start='+ event.start +'&end=' + event.end + '&id=' + event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {   
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
        url: '/php/get-events.php',
        failure: function() {
          document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display =
          bool ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

The following is where I get the data which successfully displays events on the calendar.

```
"php/get-events.php"

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("Select id,task_name,start,end,notes,task_type,status from tasks where attendees like ".$attendees);
$stmt->execute();
//$stmt->debugDumpParams();
foreach ($stmt as $row){
    $rawdata[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'title'=> $row['task_name'], 'start'=> $row['start'], 'end'=> $row['end']);
}
$rawdata = json_encode($rawdata);
echo $rawdata;
```

The following is the update file, which it is getting into ok, but the echo's I try to display are all undefined.

```
/* Values received via ajax */
echo "id -".$_POST['id'];
echo "start -".$_POST['start'];
echo "end -".$_POST['end'];

// update the records
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE tasks SET start=?, end=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->execute($_POST['start'], $_POST['end'], $_POST['id']);
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

It may be something simple, but from the documentation I've read, I can't seem to figure out why my variables are not posting successfully. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop ...what you're calling `event` isn't an event.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmm, should I be using "var event = calendar.getEventById('a')" to first define the event object, then reference start,end and id variables using event.start etc?

Comment: No that wasn't what I meant. That would get you the same event every time, not the one which was dropped. Look at the function signature of eventDrop, compared to what you've written

Comment: `function(event, delta) {` vs `function( eventDropInfo ) {`...and then look at the documentation further down to see where you _do_ get the event data from within that object. There's an example as well

Comment: @ADyson - Ok I've looked through there, do you think if I change `eventDrop: function(event, delta)` to   `eventDrop: function(info)` and then change my variables from event.start etc to info.event.start , that would be the solution? It almost seems too good to be true, does the info function not need defined or created somewhere? Or it's built in to fullcalendar? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I expect that should work. You might perhaps want to use startStr and endStr (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) to get a better format for transmission.

Comment: `does the info function not need defined or created somewhere`...not sure what you mean? `info` isn't a function, it's an object. fullCalendar provides that object, ready-populated, into the callback when it executes it. You provide the definition of the callback to be executed, and then when the relevant event occurs, fullCalendar executes it and populates the values in the signature, as per that documentation.

Comment: @ADyson - Perfect, works thanks very much. Do you want to create an answer and I'll mark it? Could I ask one final question related to my calendar initiation. I've seen alot of examples out there which use  `var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({}` compared to mine `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {}`. From what I can tell they do very similar/the same thing, but was just wondering if my method is ok? If I try to change to the jquery way, I get so many errors trying to include files because it's within a calendar.blade laravel page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar` is simply syntax from an earlier version (v3 and below) when fullCalendar was implemented as a jQuery plugin. Your way is correct for your version. If you tried that other way, it would simply error.

Comment: @ADyson Ok good to know, appreciated. FINAL thing I promise, it's a slightly different question but very minor, I want to output the date time for db entry ('YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') from the toISOString, but all I can find is how to output it in 'YY-MM-DD' using .substring(0,10). I tried using .format on the variable but it says it's not a function or something.

Comment: Sorry it's a bit unclear what you mean? Which variable are you trying to use it on? toISOString is a separate function, it has nothing to with .format (which isn't a function of a Date object anyway)

Comment: Yeah sorry nevermind, I was being stupid, I just used moment.format to pass the data in the format I want. Really appreciate the help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for your `eventDrop` signature. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop

It should be

```
eventDrop: function(info) {
```

And then replace

```
event.start
```

and

```
event.end
```

with

```
info.event.start
```

and

```
info.event.end
```

This will get the information you need correctly from the data which fullCalendar supplies.